# How to fix a "arguments did not match any overloaded call" error

Tags: qgis

I'm making a geological map with the use of `SpatialLite` points, lines and polygons, but suddenly `QGIS` showed all kind of errors and decided it doesn't want to load my maps and SpatialLite layers any more. It happened when I clicked on a map layer to turn it on.

This is what it says:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   QSize(): too
>   many arguments   QSize(int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type
>   'long'   QSize(QSize): argument 1 has unexpected type 'long' 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/kikid/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py",
>   line 125, in request
>       self.setup_map()   File "C:/Users/kikid/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py",
>   line 201, in setup_map
>       olSize = QSize(int(olWidth), int(olHeight)) TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   QSize(): too many arguments
>   QSize(int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'   QSize(QSize):
>   argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'
>
> Python versie: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64
>   bit (AMD64)]  QGIS versie: 2.18.6 Las Palmas, 5f369b0
>
> Python pad:
>   C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
>   C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python C:/Users/kikid/.qgis2/python
>   C:/Users/kikid/.qgis2/python/plugins
>   C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
>   C:/Users/kikid/.qgis2//python C:/Users/kikid/Desktop/Kiki BSc

I tried to load my SpatialLite layers in a different `QGIS` map and that worked, it only didn't contain all data and colours I gave it, so it will be a loooot of work to fix that all.

Is there any way to get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the open layers plugin, it looks like this is what is causing the issue

Comment: No, I just tried and it worked!! Thank you so much, you made my day!

Comment: @Freight_Train Please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as solved