# Error in executing clip with polygon from another layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3

I have used `clip with polygon from another layer` with the `Digitizing tools` toolbar successfully before but I am running into an error recently.

I have selected one polygon in the layer to clip and one polygon in the clipping layer. Both layers have the same CRS (they are actually polygons copied from the same layer initially just so I could perform the clipping operation).

I do not have `openlayers plugin` installed (potential issue raised in [How to fix a "arguments did not match any overloaded call" error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243221/how-to-fix-a-arguments-did-not-match-any-overloaded-call-error))

> TypeError: QgsCoordinateTransform(): arguments did not match any
>   overloaded call:    overload 1: too many arguments    overload 2:
>   argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'    overload 3: argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'int'    overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type
>   'int'    overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Kellina\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools\dtclipper.py",
>   line 107, in process
>       clipperCRSSrsid, projectCRSSrsid TypeError: QgsCoordinateTransform(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   overload 1: too many arguments   overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected
>   type 'int'   overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
>   overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'   overload 5:
>   argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
>
> Version de Python : 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12)
>   [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]  Version de QGIS : 3.0.1-Girona Girona,
>   a86bec25eb
>
> Chemin Python : C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python
>   C:/Users/Kellina/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
>   C:/Users/Kellina/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
>   C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins C:\Program Files\QGIS
>   3.0\bin\python36.zip C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\DLLs C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36
>   C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages
>   C:/Users/Kellina/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
>   C:\Users\Kellina\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools
>   J:/MRC Granit/identification des MHH

Comment: With the same features, I just used the `clipper` plugin without issues. http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/clipper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the DigitizingTools plugin - you should report it to the plugin's author.

Comment: Not sure how to report to puglin's author directly but I've made report on the general bug tracker site: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19797

Comment: The bug has been fixed by the author as of version 1.2.0 of the plugin.